# Is Tribal a permanent type (for Muldrotha)?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am building a Commander deck with [Muldrotha, the Gravetide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMuldrotha%2c%20the%20Gravetide%5d) as the Commander. During my deckbuilding, I remembered there is such a thing as a "Tribal" card type. Is Tribal one of the supported card types that can be cast from the graveyard using Muldrotha's ability?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tribal is a card type but not a permanent type.  So Tribal counts for cards like [Tarmogoyf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTarmogoyf%5d), but not [Muldrotha, the Gravetide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMuldrotha%2c%20the%20Gravetide%5d).

From the comprehensive rules:

> 110.4. There are five permanent types: artifact, creature, enchantment, land, and planeswalker.
>
> 300.1. The card types are artifact, conspiracy, creature, enchantment, instant, land, phenomenon, plane, planeswalker, scheme, sorcery, tribal, and vanguard.